# socket is set with O_NONBLOCK, but it seems the calling thread still gets into sleep when sending data sometimes

Tags: c, sockets

1. Client

In fact, my client doesn't recv and process data send from server, just connects to my server.

```
    int netif_msg_client_socket_create(char *sockpath)
    {

        int addrlen, retval;
        int sockfd;
        struct sockaddr_un serv;

        sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(sockfd < 0) {
    PR_ERROR(NETIF_MSG_M, " fatal failure, client msg socket, error is %s, %s %u\n", strerror(errno), __FILE__, __LINE__);
            return -1;
       }

       /* Make client socket. */
       memset (&serv, 0, sizeof (struct sockaddr_un));
       serv.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
       strncpy (serv.sun_path, sockpath, strlen(sockpath));

       addrlen = sizeof (serv.sun_family) + strlen(serv.sun_path);

       retval = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv, addrlen);
       if(retval < 0)
       {
            PR_ERROR(NETIF_MSG_M, " fatal failure, client msg connect, error is %s, %s %u\n", strerror(errno), __FILE__, __LINE__);
            close(sockfd);
            return -1;
       }

       fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

       return sockfd;
    }
```

2.Server

But my server will try to send some data to the client continuously.

```
    int netif_msg_server_socket_create(char *sockpath)
    {

        int addrlen, retval;
        int sockfd;
        struct sockaddr_un serv;

        /* First of all, unlink existing socket */
        unlink (sockpath);

        sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(sockfd < 0)
            return -1;

        fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

        /* Make server socket. */
        memset (&serv, 0, sizeof (struct sockaddr_un));
        serv.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strncpy (serv.sun_path, sockpath, sizeof(serv.sun_path)-1);

        addrlen = sizeof (serv.sun_family) + strlen(serv.sun_path);
        //printf("sizeof(serv) == %d, addrlen == %d.\r\n", sizeof(serv), addrlen);

        retval = bind (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv, addrlen);
        if (retval < 0)
        {
            close (sockfd); /* Avoid sd leak. */
            return -1;
        }

        retval = listen (sockfd, 20);
        if (retval < 0)
        {
            close (sockfd); /* Avoid sd leak. */
            return -1;
        }

        return sockfd;
    }
```

1. My server uses select and accepts the connection from my client successfully.
2. After my server sent 412 packets(96 Bytes each), it seems the server sleeps on send.

Key codes:

```
    printf("Try to send packet(%d bytes) to clientfd %d.\n", MSGCB_DLEN(msgcb), client->acpt_fd);

    retval = send(client->acpt_fd, msgcb->data_ptr, MSGCB_DLEN(msgcb), 0);
    if(retval != MSGCB_DLEN(msgcb))
    {
        printf("Send netif notify msg failed[%d].\n", retval);
    } else {
    printf("Send netif notify msg succeeded.\n");
    }
```

After 412 packets sent to my client and "Try to ..." outputed, nothing goes on, neither "...failed" nor "...succeeded" outputs.

1. I use getsockopt to fetch the SO_RCVBUF and SO_SNDBUF, there are about 100000Bytes for each of them.
2. I don't know why, need your help, thanks!

Comment: you're on the right track.  All socket IO should be non-blocking, even if you're polling to see if there is data to read and write, it's not guaranteed to be there by the time you get around to checking for it, so if you're not non-blocking, you may block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the server socket that is connected to the client to be non-blocking, then you must specifically set the new socket that is returned from `accept()` to be non-blocking.  Your code only sets the listening socket to non-blocking.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform non-blocking I/O with `send` using the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag in the last parameter.

```
    retval = send(client->acpt_fd, msgcb->data_ptr, MSGCB_DLEN(msgcb),
                  MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

When performing non-blocking I/O, you need to detect when the return value is signalling you to retry the operation.

```
    if (retval < 0) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN) {
            /* ... handle retry of send laster when it is ready ... */
        } else {
            /* ... other error value cases */
        }
    }
```